# c++ fmt library - undefined reference

Tags: c++, fmt

I am trying to use the `fmt` library, however without success.

```
#define FMT_HEADER_ONLY

#include <fmt/os.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
  auto out = fmt::output_file("fmt.txt");
  out.print("Test no. {}", "1");
}
```

I got a bunch of errors. It seems it is linked to linker but how if I use only header only fmt.
I use Codeblocks (MinGW GCC) and add in "search directories" `fmt-9.0.0\include` directory.

```
||=== Build: Release in _GENERAL_TEST_2 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
....\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\..\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\12.1.0\..\..\..\..\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe: obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN3fmt2v97ostreamD1Ev[_ZN3fmt2v97ostreamD1Ev]+0x2c)||undefined reference to `fmt::v9::file::write(void const*, unsigned long long)'|
....\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\..\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\12.1.0\..\..\..\..\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe: obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN3fmt2v97ostreamD1Ev[_ZN3fmt2v97ostreamD1Ev]+0x50)||undefined reference to `fmt::v9::file::~file()'|
....\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\..\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\12.1.0\..\..\..\..\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe: obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x46)||undefined reference to `fmt::v9::file::file(fmt::v9::basic_cstring_view<char>, int)'|
....\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\..\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\12.1.0\..\..\..\..\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe: obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xd4)||undefined reference to `fmt::v9::file::~file()'|
....\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\..\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\12.1.0\..\..\..\..\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe: obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZTVN3fmt2v97ostreamE[.refptr._ZTVN3fmt2v97ostreamE]+0x0)||undefined reference to `vtable for fmt::v9::ostream'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 6 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 6 second(s)) ===|
```

Answer (score 2):

The fmtlib documentation is incomplete. It fails to clearly state that in header-only mode you can only use a subset of the APIs, and to define this subset.

It is safest to assume that in header-only mode you can *only* include `<fmt/format.h>`.

Comment: I deleted #define FMT_HEADER_ONLY, but it does not help. The errors still remains, there are only much more of them, 50 of undefined reference.

Comment: @TomášNadrchal If you are not using FMT_HEADER_ONLY, you need to link with the library, obviously.

Comment: This I do not understand. FTM v 9.0.0 includes only header files and than 3 cc files fmt.cc, format.cc, os.cc. Even if I put all the files into fmt folder of the project and add them to the project. However it generates different errors.    ||=== Build: Release in _GENERAL_TEST_2 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
....\fmt\core.h|2882|error: 'template<int N, class T, class ... Args, class Char> constexpr int fmt::v9::detail::get_arg_index_by_name(fmt::v9::basic_string_view<Char>)' references internal linkage entity 'constexpr const int fmt::v9::detail::invalid_arg_index'|

Comment: This is a different error and a different question.